# get version before changeset TFS / VSO

Tags: tfs, version-control, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Developer Check in 240 files into a Changeset #300, in our VSO repo.

I have scripts to pull out files in a changeset to then deploy to different environments. so I have all the files from Changeset 300, and copied them to the server just to find out they were wrong.

FYI: part of that script is:

```
foreach($i in $ChangesetIDS){& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools\tfpt.exe" "getcs" "/changeset:$i"}
```

I need to roll back the changes made in the Changeset!  But it is not like Changeset #299 has the version just before the one stored in #300.

Is there a way to only pull the files associated with Changeset #300 
but from whatever the last time that file was checked in (making the assumption #300 is not always the latest version in the repository.)

Comment: Changeset #299 _definitely_ has the version just before #300.  What if you do a *get* at that version (which will get the file *as it exists at version 299*) instead of a *getcs* (which only gets the files *changed in that changeset*)

Comment: Why do you need the previous changeset?  Can't you just roll back changeset 300?

Comment: Well, C300 may not be *all* bad.  It's several hundred files after all.  Rollback is just syntactical sugar, and if you want to preserve part of a changeset, the manual process might be more useful.

Comment: I currently don't deploy the entire "vault" when I move changes to QA and Training - because it is not a straight forward .net project.  I only move files from C300, and if I want to undo that I would like to only pull the files from C300 but from C299 *the last version.

Answer (score 0):

As Christopher said above that you need to rollback changeset 300, and check in the rollback changes, let's say changeset 301. Then changeset 301 contains all files with a previous version of changeset 300.

However, changeset 300 still exists even if you roll back it. You need to [destroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399141(v=vs.100).aspx) it if you want to delete it permanently.

Comment: So the only way to get the roll'ed back changes from 300 to 299 regardless of if I destroy 300 or check them back in as 301 - is to move the entire file set to the destination server, I can't select ONLY the files that were changed?

Comment: @PHPFouts, via opening the details of the changeset, it is possible for you to check files that are associated with that changeset. And what's the "destination server" you're referring to? If you mean the local machine you want to get these files, then there is nothing you need to worry about, when you get specific version based on changesetid, only changes in that changeset are downloaded.